# Get input value and redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to get the text input from the form and redirect it to antother page, using js?

```
<form action="">
<input type="text" name="query" id="query" />
<input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

and, on submit, redirect to something like this:

*site.com/search/* **INPUT_TEXT_HERE**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect after posting a HTML form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092226/redirect-after-posting-a-html-form)

Answer (score 1):

Just use jquery's `val()` to get the value of your input and `window.location.replace` to redirect to the url you want.

Finally execute your code when the form is submitted using jquery's `submit` function

In order to prevent the form from submitting you should use jquery's `preventDefault()`

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
window.location.replace("site.com/search/"+$("#query").val());
})
```

Comment: thanks, that works, but if in the form i set method="post/get" , it doesnt work, how can i prevent the default behavior? thanks in advanced and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Although in your case you do not have to set a method I updated my answer.Just use `preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

`<form action="place ur URL/>;`  and write your code.when you click on `submit`.it will be redirected to some given link.